# Show multiple objects values as a Input values in forms Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a  array of objects getting from api like this

[0: {id: 1, name: "dine", restaurant: 2}
 1: {id: 2, name: "pick", restaurant: 2}]

Now I want to show this just name of these both objects like this  **`dine,pick`**   . I was able to show this in a div like this

```
 {articleopt.ingredient.map(ingred => (
                                <div>{ingred.name + ","}</div>
                              ))}
```

But how can I assign this to a form input field value= {}   ?  My input field code is

```
<div className='col-sm-6'>
                <div className='form-group text-left'>
                  <label htmlFor='' className='small'>
                    Ingredient:
                  </label>
                  <InputField 
                  name='ingredient'
                  value={""}
                  placeholder={"Enter Ingredient comma separated"} />
                </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have some data like this, you can map/join the array down to a comma-separated string.

```
const data = [{id: 1, name: "dine", restaurant: 2}, {id: 2, name: "pick", restaurant: 2}];
const combined = data.map(el => el.name).join(",");
```

You can render JSX as follows:

```
<div className='form-group text-left'>
  <InputField value={combined} />
</div>
```

Comment: thanks sir for answer .your solution is creating two fields , I want this data in one field with comma separated

Comment: Oh I see, so you just want one field ever?

Comment: Yes Exactly . One field with comma separated names

Comment: Updated! Let me know if this is what you're looking for

Comment: got it . thanks <3 is there any resources to read for issues like this ?  kindly refer if any you have